# Posting to Handler tied to current thread

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a Handler, `mHandler`, tied to the main thread. `mHandler` resides in a `Service`. Say I now post a `Runnable` to `mHandler` from the main thread like so:

```
public class SomeService extends Service {
    // Handler is created on the main thread
    // (and hence it is tied to the main thread)
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // onDestroy runs on the main thread
        // Is the code in this Runnable processed right away?
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            // (Some code statements that are to be run on the main thread)
            ...
        });
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I know the example is a little silly as the `Handler` is unnecessary. However, it is a good example for this question.

Now my questions are:

1. Will the code statements in the `Runnable` be processed right away as the thread that posts the `Runnable` is also the thread that is to process the `Runnable`? Or does it work differently as the `Handler` internally uses a `MessageQueue` and hence there might be `Runnable`s posted to the `Handler` elsewhere (which arrive before my `Runnable`)?
2. Moreover, is it possible that the statements will never run as the `post(Runnable r)` is an async call and hence `onDestroy()` will finish and the `Service` will be killed by the system before the `Handler` gets to run the code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since a `Service` does not imply a separate thread, your runnable will be posted at the end of the main `Looper`'s queue, so yes, there may be messages/runnables scheduled before yours.
2. Again, since `Service` does not imply a distinct thread, a call to `onDestroy` does not mean that the `Handler`'s thread has been terminated. In this example, you are posting to the main looper, and that thread is active until the application process terminates.

Comment: I am more concerned about the service lifecycle than the thread of the Handler. I assume that as onDestroy() finishes, the service and hence the Handler are now dead and hence free for garbage collection. Now if the service is cleared before the Runnable is scheduled, I assume that the Runnable will never run...?

Comment: If you are posting to the main looper's queue, the main looper holds a reference to its queue (Which the handler will proxy runnables to), so your runnable will be ineligible for GC until it executes.

Comment: and as the Handler is part of the service, the service will be kept alive as well?

Comment: No. `onDestroy` means that the service has been destroyed.