# How do I delay execution in a Service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have an Android Service which extends IntentService where I call:

```
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Start your app main activity
      }
    }, LaunchActivity.SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
  }
```

The former code works fine in an Activity but the `run()` method is never called in a Service method.

**How do I delay execution in a Service?**

Comment: Can you share the code with the service?

Comment: IMO, you can read the following link http://binarybuffer.com/2012/07/executing-scheduled-periodic-tasks-in-android

Comment: There is no more code. I just want to delay an execution in a Service. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to show in what (lifecycle) method this code resides. Or is it part of field initialisation? You also need to clarify on what thread this code is invoked. The handler is tied to the thread that creates it.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken See my edit. It is in ``onHandleIntent ``.

Comment: Does your `Service` extend `IntentService`?

Comment: Yes the Service extends IntentService.

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating the `Handler` as part of `onHandleIntent`, it is tied to the worker thread associated with the `IntentService`. According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)), the system automatically terminates the `IntentService` when `onHandleIntent` returns if there are no other pending requests. My guess is that the system determines that all requests have been handled as you return from `onHandleIntent` and terminates the worker thread even though there is still delayed work on the work queue of that worker thread.

You should be able to test this hypothesis by invoking your code inside a service lifecycle method that runs on the main thread, e.g. `onStartCommand`. Assuming that your application is not killed by the system in the timeframe between the invocation of your code and the specified delay, and the code gets to execute, then the issue you are facing is most likely connected to premature termination of the worker thread on which you queue your `Runnable`. The main looper stays alive as long as your application stays alive, and as such your code should eventually run when queued using the main looper. See the answer and comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28618685/1214974).

Comment: How does Looper works? Could oyu giv an example please?

Comment: You don't nessecarily need to understand Looper in order to perform the described test. All you need to do is run your code (new Handler().postDelayed(...)) on the main thread. However, for reference see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: I do not need to do the test. That is the problem I know.

Comment: Well if the answer helped you identify your problem, please be a gentleman and mark it as the accepted answer ;).

Comment: Well, you did not solve my problem. How do I delay something in a service?

Comment: You need to describe more thoroughly what you're trying to accomplish. Is there a particular reason that you are using an IntentService as opposed to a regular started Service?

Comment: I want to delay a function in a onHandleIntent() method of a IntentService extend.

Comment: If it needs to in an IntentService, I see no other option than to sleep the thread during onHandleIntent and then run your code after this sleep. However, this is a horrible design choice. Again: what are you trying to do that specifically needs an IntentService as opposed to a regular Service?

Comment: The difference between a regular Service and an IntentService is described very well in the the developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
Be warned that a regular Service runs on the main thread, so you should avoid lengthy and blocking computations unless you explicitly spawn a background worker thread for this purpose within the Service.

Comment: Why couldn't you just answer my question?

Comment: What question? You're not providing enough details on what it is you want the service to do. I asked you twice why you've picked an IntentService rather than a regular (started) Service for your usecase, but you simply ignored me.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Read the developer guide I linked, it explains it well. In short: IntentService is for shorter background jobs that are to run on a worker thread in order not to block the main thread. Service: lets you run code (for a long time) even though your application is not in the foreground.